# Jackson parse different level fields to one java class

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have the following JSON string and java class.
Json:

```json
{
    "records": [
        {
            "metadata": {
                "id": "1129836408668",
                "partition": "ecp:9-ca69437a-2ad5-4233-bfc4-fd9aa049569d",
                "version": "ecp:9-f66cf504-ba65-48a9-91c0-d1d8229e4899",
                "currentAt": "2021-12-07T11:13:50.699Z"
            },
            "state": {
                "effectiveFrom": "2021-12-14T06:35:09.063Z",
                "effectiveTo": "2021-12-14T06:35:09.063Z",
                "currentFrom": "2021-12-14T06:35:09.063Z",
                "currentTo": "2021-12-14T06:35:09.063Z",
                "dataItem": {
                    "ModifiedDate": "2021-12-07T11:13:44.099Z",
                    "ObjectId": "1129836408668",
                    "ChangeFlag": "",
                    "IsUnconfirmed": "false",
                    "CreatedDate": "2021-12-07T11:13:44.099Z"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "index": null
}
```

Class A:

```java
public class ParentClass {
    
    private Date effectiveFrom;
    private Date effectiveTo;
    private Date currentFrom;
    private Date currentTo;
    private String id;
}
```

Class B

```java
public class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    
    @JsonProperty("ModifiedDate")
    private Date ModifiedDate;
    
    @JsonProperty("ObjectId")
    private String ObjectId;
    
    @JsonProperty("ChangeFlag")
    private String ChangeFlag;
    
    @JsonProperty("IsUnconfirmed")
    private String IsUnconfirmed;
    
    @JsonProperty("CreatedDate")
    private Date CreatedDate;
    
}
```

And I'd like to parse the values in `state` jsonnode to `ChildClass` wiht Jackson. Which way is the best way to do it.
My thoughts is trying to parse `state` into MapA, and then parse `dateItem` into MapB, then merge MapB to MapA, you will get a Mapc, and then parse MapC to `ChildClass`. However, I think this is not a efficiency way to do it. So will you guys have a better solution.

MapC:

```
{
effectiveFrom=2021-12-14T06:35:09.063Z, 
effectiveTo=2021-12-14T06:35:09.063Z, 
currentFrom=2021-12-14T06:35:09.063Z, 
currentTo=2021-12-14T06:35:09.063Z, 
ModifiedDate=2021-12-07T11:13:44.099Z, 
ObjectId=1129836408668, 
ChangeFlag=, IsUnconfirmed=false, 
CreatedDate=2021-12-07T11:13:44.099Z
}
```

Comment: A possible alternative is create a `DataItem` class and include it in a `State` class using composition instead of inheritance, have you tried this approach ?

Comment: create a State class is not a way I want. So far, my solution is parse this json to `Map<String, Object>` and then merge all the elements into one Map, then parse the map to java bean.

Comment: The alternative I proposed is about deserialize the json file with `State state = mapper.readValue(json, State.class)`, inheritance in jackson can be achieved indicating in the json file the type of the subclass you want to deserialize.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need two classes. You need just one that is capable of deserializing `dataItem` block in a customized way. Something along the following lines should work:

```java
public class ParentClass {
    
    private Date effectiveFrom;
    private Date effectiveTo;
    private Date currentFrom;
    private Date currentTo;
    private String id;
    
    private Date modifiedDate;
    private String objectId;
    private String changeFlag;
    private String isUnconfirmed;
    private Date createdDate;

    @JsonProperty("dataItem")
    private void unpackNested(Map<String, Object> dataItem) {
        this.modifiedDate = Date.from(Instant.from(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.parse((String) dataItem.get("ModifiedDate"))));
        this.objectId = (String) dataItem.get("ObjectId");
        this.changeFlag = (String) dataItem.get("ChangeFlag");
        this.isUnconfirmed = (String) dataItem.get("IsUnconfirmed");
        this.createdDate = Date.from(Instant.from(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.parse((String) dataItem.get("CreatedDate"))));
    }
    
}
```

You can find other options at https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-nested-values.